# How can you use captured groups of sed as key for dictionary in bash

Tags: regex, bash, dictionary, sed

I am using sed to do some pattern matching and extract bits and pieces from some input, and I want to use these captured groups as indexes to access elements in a dictionary.

For example I want the code below:

```
TASK_TO_IP["task1"]=127.0.0.1
echo "sent task1 to slave" | sed -rn "s/sent ([[:graph:]]+) .*/Found ${TASK_TO_IP[\1]}/p"
```

to output: `Found 127.0.0.1`

Instead I'm getting: `Found`

How can I use the captured group of sed as key to this dictionary?

Comment: I have almost the same issue and was interested to see if anyone else has asked this before - StackOverflow lived up to the expectations! But in the end I decided I will just write it in python to make it simple.

Answer (score 3):

Parameter expansion will occur before sed is invoked. You'll have to do something like (untested):

```
output=$(
  echo "sent task1 to slave" | 
  sed -rn 's/sent ([[:graph:]]+) .*/Found ${TASK_TO_IP[\1]}/p'
)
eval echo "$output"
```

I would take a different approach: first extract the task id from the string, then use it for the hash lookup:

```
line="sent task1 to slave"
taskid=$( grep -oP 'sent \K\w+' <<< "$line" )
echo "Found ${TASK_TO_IP[$taskid]}"
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a wrapper script here. Use `sed` to get `task1` and store it in a variable.

```
var="$(sed 's/sent \([^ ]*\).*/\1/' <<< 'sent task1 to slave')"
```

and then

```
echo "${TASK_TO_IP[$var]}"
```